# How can I retrieve ant property into teamcity

Tags: maven, ant, properties, teamcity

I am configuring teamcity project for ant. I know I can retrieve maven build number from pom.xml using `${maven.build.number}` into teamcity. I am not getting how to retrieve the same from ant xml. I have configured a property in ant file for version.

```
<project xmlns:artifact="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant">
<property  name="version" value="1.0.0.16"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Teamcity provides a large number of properties that are automatically made available to your ANT build (via System properties). In your specific case the Teamcity build number is available as:

```
<property name="version" value="${build.number}"/>
```

There are dozens of other properties you can make available as well, consult [the Teamcity Docs](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Predefined+Build+Parameters)